# How to Visualize a matplotlib prediction using a tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a scenario where I made a prediction on a particular dataset. Now I want to visualize that predicted graph using Tkinter.

My Machine Learning Model looks as below which consists of a graph:

```
# Importing Libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sys

# Importing the Batsmen Dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Batsmen/Batsmen.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]].values

# Using Elbow Method to find the optimal number of Clusters
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()
```

I tried as shown below:

```
from tkinter import *

# these four imports are important
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def plot():
    # Importing Libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import sys

    # Importing the Batsmen Dataset
    dataset = pd.read_csv('Batsmen/Batsmen.csv')
    X = dataset.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]].values

    # Using Elbow Method to find the optimal number of Clusters
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    wcss = []
    for i in range(1, 11):
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)
        kmeans.fit(X)
        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

root = Tk()

def app():
    # initialise a window.
    root = Tk()
    root.config(background='white')
    root.geometry("1000x700")

    lab = Label(root, text="Live Plotting", bg = 'white').pack()

    fig = Figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title('The Elbow Method')
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of Clusters')
    ax.set_ylabel('WCSS')
    ax.grid()

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

def plotter():
    ax.cla()
    ax.grid()
    dpts = plot()
    ax.plot(range(1, 11), wcss, marker='o', color='orange')
    graph.draw()
    time.sleep(1)

def gui_handler():
    threading.Thread(target=plotter).start()

b = Button(root, text="Start/Stop", command=gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
b.pack()

root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

But its not working out!

I just want to show the prediction on the Tkinter GUI and when I press the predict button in the GUI, I want the graph to be displayed inside the GUI canvas. So, Can anyone please help me in doing the same.

Comment: Read and follow [Embedding In Tk](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html?highlight=tkinter)

Comment: see link in @stovfl comment. I used this code to create other examples: https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/matplotlib-seaborn

Comment: @furas, I didn't clearly understand how the embedding is done. Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: You should show what you have tried and what you can do or ask more precise question - Stackoverflow is not a place where you ask others to do a whole task for you.

Comment: @godot, I already told that I wanted a tkinter GUI to fit the above-predicted graph.

Comment: @godot, Now that I have added what I have already tried, you can check it and help me if you can.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. If I may, it's also a bit short to say: "But its not working out!",  if you want to encourage people to help you, you have to explain what kind of error/bad behavior you are facing.

Comment: see my [minimal examples with matplot in tkinter](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/embed-matplotlib/minimal-examples) - check `main-1.py`

Comment: tkinter is not thread-safe so other threads should change tkinter elements.

Comment: did you run this code in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see error messages ? always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: in new code is wrong indention `mainloop()` is executed before you run `app()`

Comment: @furas, its not working even if I put it after the run app() command.

Comment: you have few mistakes, not one in code - so when you repair only one then it still wiil not work. See new code in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works for me if I use `root.after()` instead of threading.

Probably in most GUI frameworks thread should (or can't) change element in GUI.

On my computer yoru code with threading ends work when I press button which runs thread.

I run `plotter` whic doesn't use `while` and `sleep` but `after(1000, plotter)` to run it again after 1000ms (1s)

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint

# these two imports are important
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

continuePlotting = False

def change_state():
    global continuePlotting
    if continuePlotting == True:
        continuePlotting = False
    else:
        continuePlotting = True


def data_points():
    f = open("data.txt", "w")
    for i in range(10):
        f.write(str(randint(0, 10))+'\n')
    f.close()

    f = open("data.txt", "r")
    data = f.readlines()
    f.close()

    l = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        l.append(int(data[i].rstrip("\n")))
    return l

def app():
    # initialise a window.
    root = Tk()
    root.config(background='white')
    root.geometry("1000x700")

    lab = Label(root, text="Live Plotting", bg = 'white').pack()

    fig = Figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_xlabel("X axis")
    ax.set_ylabel("Y axis")
    ax.grid()

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

    def plotter():
        if continuePlotting:
            ax.cla()
            ax.grid()
            dpts = data_points()
            ax.plot(range(10), dpts, marker='o', color='orange')
            graph.draw()
            root.after(1000, plotter)

    def gui_handler():
        change_state()
        plotter()

    b = Button(root, text="Start/Stop", command=gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

---

**EDIT:** in new code you don't run loop so you don't need threading or `after()`

But you have other basic problems:

You have wrong indention and `mainloop()` is outside `app()` - it is executed before `app()`

In previous version `plotter` was inside `app()` - if you need it outside then you have problem with local variables - like `ax` - and you have to use `global` to have access to these variables in other function. Or you have to run function with this values as arguments - ie. `plotter(ax, wcss, graph)`

This version use `global` and it works for me. I don't have your CSV and I don't want to run `sklearn` so I put some fake data.

```
from tkinter import *

# these four imports are important
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

def plot():
    # Importing Libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import sys

    # Importing the Batsmen Dataset
#    dataset = pd.read_csv('Batsmen/Batsmen.csv')
    dataset = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': range(10),
        'b': range(10),
        'c': range(10),
        'd': range(10),
        'e': range(10),
        'f': range(10),
        'g': range(10),
    })

    X = dataset.iloc[:, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]].values

    # Using Elbow Method to find the optimal number of Clusters
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

    global wcss
    wcss = range(1, 11)
    #wcss = []
#    for i in range(1, 11):
#        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=i, init='k-means++', n_init=10, max_iter=300, random_state=0)
#        kmeans.fit(X)
#        wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)

def plotter():
    global wcss
    global ax
    global graph

    ax.cla()
    ax.grid()
    dpts = plot()
    ax.plot(range(1, 11), wcss, marker='o', color='orange')
    graph.draw()

def gui_handler():
    plotter()

def app():
    global ax
    global graph

    # initialise a window.
    root = Tk()
    root.config(background='white')
    root.geometry("1000x700")

    lab = Label(root, text="Live Plotting", bg = 'white').pack()

    fig = Figure()

    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.set_title('The Elbow Method')
    ax.set_xlabel('Number of Clusters')
    ax.set_ylabel('WCSS')
    ax.grid()

    graph = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    graph.get_tk_widget().pack(side="top",fill='both',expand=True)

    b = Button(root, text="Start/Stop", command=gui_handler, bg="red", fg="white")
    b.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app()
```

Comment: I am sorry with the previous code. I posted the wrong one. I just edited and changed it to the correct one.

Comment: your new code display figure only once so you don't need threading. If you run it without threading then it may works.

Comment: yes, I have removed it and ran the program. I am getting an error as follows:
` 
ax.cla()
NameError: name 'ax' is not defined
`

Comment: because you have local variable `ax` and you what to use it in another function.